# Password Manager, integrated with Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, password-management

We have several passwords and key phrases that we need to store in a central place.  However, we need to protect this information so others cannot access it.

Our thoughts are to have a password manager that integrates with active directory. By integrating with Active Directory, I mean control who can access saved passwords by seeing if they are a member of a certain group.

Anybody know of any password managers that meet this criteria, or have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [password manager pro](http://www.manageengine.com/products/passwordmanagerpro/) with pretty good success.  It integrates with both LDAP and AD.

Comment: Password Manager Pro can also reset service accounts to sync with the AD.  So no more Password Never Expires on those service accounts.

Comment: it can reset all builtin accounts as well so you can have local admin be a complex password that you are forced to look up.  The auditing feature can then tell you who had to look up local admin

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people (my team included) use KeePass. It's not AD-integrated, but you can restrict the folder it's in to just the people who should see it, and only share the password with them.

Answer (score 0):

password safe is the tool of choice here.

No AD integration but folder security should help with that.

We also run nightly backups of the safe folder and keep them . . . forever.

Answer (score 0):

PasswordState could also be an option.
It supports Active Directory integration.